# Draft.js only expose content

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm building a simple text editor that relies on Draft.js for decorating the text (mainly highlighting). I really like how simple it is to build a reliable input that has custom syntax highlighting.

However, I do not like the fact that I have to expose the entire editor state to do this. I'd prefer to have an editor that has just a `value` property that takes a string and passes a string trough the `onChange` prop.

This seems a reasonable thing to be able to do, yet I'm dumbfounded by how hard it is to transfer selection state.

Because of how draft.js is implemented, I find this hard to do. I need to create a new editorState based on the `value` prop every time it changes, which is doable, But it is hard to transfer `selectionState` between the old `editorState` and the new one because the `selectionState` relies on opaque identifiers that are unique to each state.

Has anyone tried to accomplish this? Is draft.js overkill for this an should I use a simpler solution that also works? I'm only using the decorators so I guess it would not be super-hard to just rebuild that part.

Comment: You need to keep your `editorState` intact until you absolutely need to convert it to text. the editorstate contains the selection state, the decorators, the undo stack as well as bunch of other things so if you create a new editorstate everytime you make a content change things will break.

So my advice would be to keep the editorstate intact, and convert it to a string or json when you save it to the server or do something else with it.

You would really benefit from joining the draft.js slack btw -
 https://draftjs.herokuapp.com/